# how to Enable gzip compression in all php pages

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, compression, gzip

Gzip compression only compress this page http://www.joojbe.com/, cannot compress http://www.joojbe.com/index this url how to fix it

my .htaccess code

```
 <IfModule mod_gzip.c>
 mod_gzip_on Yes
 mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php?|pl)$
 mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
</IfModule>
```

How to fix this problem please help me....

Comment: Is it Apache webserver or nginx webserver ?

Comment: iam using apache webserver @  Deep Kakkar

Comment: Any one else.. please help me..

Comment: Please approve the suggested edit as it contains new tags so it results better

Comment: there is a link for you https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html

Comment: sorry cannot understand this article..